# Kitchen sink strainer stuck

Tags: plumbing

I've tried every tool,wrench,chisel, hammer I've been told to use.what do I use to cut a sink strainer locknut off?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the stubborn locknut?

Answer (score 1):

I've used mini (compact) hacksaws or multi saws, and a bit of patience.

[image]
[image]

An oscillating multitool might also do the job.

[image]

Carefully heating the nut with a torch, can sometimes loosen it up. Just make sure you've rinsed/wiped away any penetrating oil you've applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find a dedicated wrench designed specifically for sink drain nuts.  https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sink+basket+nut+wrench .  I've also drilled perforations into the nut face and then tapped a old flathead screwdriver under the drill holes. The nut easily broke apart at the drilled metal openings.